# DeepLens v1.1 Registration failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-classification, aws-deeplens

I have connected my DeepLens v1.1 device to my account to register and validate the devices i purchased, the device never connects to my machine (MacOSX)

I follow the steps exactly as instructed but I only receive failure after initial 2 minutes of waiting.

I connected the device to a monitor and keyboard, i updated the password to my own custom password and i tried to update the packages on the device with the following steps

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install awscam
sudo reboot
```

When I logged in to the device itself i was able to set the password accordingly also, but through the AWS Console the device does not connect.

I pressed the reset pin too

I also added MFA to the root account of the AWS account we are using.

Nothing I have done has allowed me to successfully complete the 1st step to connect the device to the account to validate and register it.

What can I do?

Comment: I could only get this to work on windows

Comment: Bezos got rid of deepLens, geeez.